# Getting printer permission output in username format

Tags: powershell, printing, permissions

I have a script that I think will work to get my printers to output their permissions in username format, I'm getting an error "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '.PermissionSDDL'

Below is my script

```
$computerfile = get-content "\\test\d$\test\Ltest\test\MW 
scripts\test.txt"
ForEach ($computer in $computerfile) {
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $computer |
Select-Object Name,Systemname, Local |
Format-Table -AutoSize
}
$printers = Get-Printer Name -Full.PermissionSDDL
ForEach ($Printer in $Printers) {
$objSID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier 
$objUser = $objSID.Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$objUser.Value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens, as object property is referred in improper a way.

This

```
$printers = Get-Printer Name -Full.PermissionSDDL
```

attempts to pass a parameter `-Full.PermissionSDDL` that Get-Printer doesn't support. What's more, the `-Name` switch is missing the switch identifier and, well, actual printer name.

The proper syntax is

```
$printers = (Get-Printer -Name $myPrinter -Full).PermissionSDDL
```

Comment: Thanks von, that seems to work but just pointed out another error in my script, I'm trying to get the permissions from my printers so I need to pull the names which the first part of the script does correctly then inject them into the second part of the script. Any ideas?